# Reading XML with "fields & values" in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

How can we read an XML like below in C# so we have  list of all fields & their corresponding values..

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd   http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd">
<businessCard>
 <field type="Phone">
  <value>+91-1234 53789</value>
 </field>
 <field type="Email">
  <value>xyz@xyz.com</value>
 </field>
 <field type="Name">
  <value>My Full Name</value>
 </field>
<field type="Company">
 <value>My Company Name</value>
</field>
<field type="Job">
 <value>Technical Lead</value>
</field>
<field type="Text">
 <value>
  My Name Technical Lead Q +91-1234-567-890 © xyz@xyz.com ▲
 </value>
</field>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you parse the xml and save it in a class/object. That way you'll have a list of `fields`, each with a `value` property.

Comment: That's the intention, however trying to load & parse an XML that has this schema does not work with XDocument.Load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the XML into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.  With the key being the `field type` and the value being the contents of `<value>`.

```
XNamespace bc = "http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd";
var fields = doc
   .Element(bc + "businessCard")
   .Elements(bc + "field")
   .ToDictionary(
       x => x.Attribute("type").Value, // key
       x => x.Element(bc + "value").Value);  // value
```

Comment: That looks like that should work.. I'll give it a try & update you with what we find. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think, this might help you more-

```
//this counter lets you count number of business cards
int iCounter = 1;
//Namespace associated with your businessCards
XNamespace xn = "http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd";
//Dictionary containing business cards with fields as their values.
var lists = xd.Elements(xn + "businessCard").ToDictionary(key => iCounter++, bus => bus.Elements(xn + "field").
            ToDictionary(key => key.Attribute("type").Value, value => value.Element(xn + "value").Value));
```